# Change rows of datas when one of them is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work in database to manage changing rooms in Google Sheets. Each changing room is composed of many lockers and each locker can be used by two people max (for example : one locker named 1 is identified by two places, one with the name 1_A and the other by the name 1_B).

I have a tab on my Sheet where I have all of my data (it's my database), another tab where I attribute lockers for the staff and the last where I can clean lockers when a member of staff leave the company.

I would like to create a script allowing to change the lockers. If a member of staff with the locker 1_A leave the company, I would like to give at the other person of the locker with the name 1_B the locker 1_A.

[image]

For the example, if Sansa leave the company (she has Locker 02_A), I would like to give to Arya the locker 02_A (with all of the information of her) and clear the row 5).

How can I proceed? I am just seeking an idea to write the apps script.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic of your question. So, I cannot understand `For the exemple, if Sansa leave the company (she have the Locker 02_A), i would like to give to Arya the locker 02_A (with all of the information of her) and clear the row 5).`. For example, how can we confirm whether someone leaves? And, in your sample image, when `Arya` leaves, what result do you want? And, when both `Sansa` and `Arya` leave, what result do you want? First, I thought that I would like to correctly understand the logic of your goal.

Comment: Dont worry, my english is more poor than yours. I confirm when someone leave in other tab. I write the id of the person, i launch a script and this script delete the personn in the data base. I don't join this script on my post because i didn't know that was necessary. but i can edit my post and join it if you want. In my picture, if Arya leave, i don't want to change something. I would like to change only if a member of staff with a locker ending with _B leave the company. Same if Ary and Sansa leave, i don't need nothing. I hope you ll understand more that what i would like

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I would like to change only if a member of staff with a locker ending with _B leave the company.`, is this situation different from the situation of `if Sansa leave the company (she have the Locker 02_A), i would like to give to Arya the locker 02_A (with all of the information of her)`? And also, I cannot understand `Same if Ary and Sansa leave, i don't need nothing.`. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the logic of your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. i would like to say " i would like to change if a member of staff with a locker ending with _A leave the company". If it was the case and i have a member in the "same locker" but ending by _B, i would like to switch him automatically in the locker _A. For exemple in the picture, if Sansa leave, i would like to give the locker 02_A to Arya. For others cases, i dont need something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var new_data = [];

  while(data.length) {
    var row_a = data.shift();
    var row_b = data.shift();

    // swap the rows A and B if there is no name in column D of row A
    // and if there is a name in column D of row B
    if (row_a[3] == '' && row_b[3] != '') {
      [row_a, row_b] = [row_b, row_a];             // swap rows
      [row_a[1], row_b[1]] = [row_b[1], row_a[1]]; // swap back the values in column B
    }
    new_data.push(row_a);
    new_data.push(row_b);
  }

  var table = [header, ...new_data];
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I succeeded to write my script !